# ¿Por qué no imprime el resultado?

Tags: java, hilos

Tengo un ejercicio de hilos, es una carrera de relevos. el tiempo de cada atleta lo averiguo con un random. Tengo una clase atleta que extiende de thread y una clase auxiliar que me ayuda con una serie de cosas. El problema es que al final del run debería de imprimir una vez ha pasado todos los hilos final de la carrera tiempo total tanto. pero por alguna razón no lo hace y no acabo de comprender por qué.

```
public class Atleta extends Thread {

    private String relevo;

    public Atleta(String relevo) {
        super(relevo);
    }

    public void run() {
        double tiempo = 0;
        synchronized (getClass()) {
            if (VAux.getTiempo() == 0) {
                System.out.println("Comienza a correr " + getName());
                tiempo = (double) (Math.random() * (11 - 9) + 9);
                VAux.setTiempo(+tiempo);
                VAux.setAcumuladorDHilos(+1);
                getClass().notifyAll();
            } else {
                System.out.println("pasa el relevo y comienza a correr " + getName());
                tiempo = (double) (Math.random() * (11 - 9) + 9);
                VAux.setTiempo(+tiempo);
                VAux.setAcumuladorDHilos(+1);
                getClass().notifyAll();
            }
            try {
                System.out.println("el dorsal: " + getName() + " ha tardado: " + tiempo);
                getClass().wait();
            } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e) {
            }
            getClass().notifyAll();
            if (VAux.hilosAUsar == VAux.getAcumuladorDHilos()) {
                System.out.println("final de la carrera, timepo total: " + VAux.getTiempo());
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

y esta la auxiliar

```
public class VAux {

    private static double tiempo = 0;
    private static int acumuladorDHilos = 0;
    public static final int hilosAUsar =4;

    public VAux() {
    }

    public static double getTiempo() {
        return tiempo;
    }

    public static void setTiempo(double tiempo) {
        VAux.tiempo = tiempo;
    }

    public static int getAcumuladorDHilos() {
        return acumuladorDHilos;
    }

    public static void setAcumuladorDHilos(int acumuladorDHilos) {
        VAux.acumuladorDHilos = acumuladorDHilos;
    }  
}
```

el main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Atleta a1 = new Atleta("1");
   Atleta a2 = new Atleta("2");
   Atleta a3 = new Atleta("3");
   Atleta a4 = new Atleta("4");
   a1.start();
   a2.start();
   a3.start();
   a4.start();
}
```

Comment: Bueno primeramente debes corregir algunos puntos en la lógica de atleta y VAux, el hecho que envíes ´VAux.setAcumuladorDHilos(+1);´ no quiere decir que va a sumas debes cambiar en la clase VAux a += `VAux.tiempo += tiempo; y  VAux.acumuladorDHilos += acumuladorDHilos;` , ademas no se si la ejecución que esperas es en orden lo cual no sucederá porque los hilos se ejecutan cuando pueda por lo que no garantizan un orden, y pasa la lógica del if `if (VAux.hilosAUsar == VAux.getAcumuladorDHilos())`  hacia arriba de `getClass().wait();` con eso obtendrás lo inicial para que sigas aprendiendo.

Comment: no me entero muy bien de que hacer en cada clase, me lo puedes explicar mejor

Comment: ya te he colocado las modificaciones como respuesta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hola te dejo algunos cambios para que logres inicialmente lo que pides que es imprimir la sección final de la carrera, tiempo total.

```
public class VAux {
    private static double tiempo = 0;
    private static int acumuladorDHilos = 0;
    public static final int hilosAUsar =4;

    public VAux() {
    }

    public static double getTiempo() {
        return tiempo;
    }

    public static void setTiempo(double tiempo) {
        // VAux.tiempo = tiempo; De esta forma solo asignas el valor de tiempo a la variable VAux.tiempo 
        // que siempre será 1.

        VAux.tiempo += tiempo;
    }

    public static int getAcumuladorDHilos() {
        return acumuladorDHilos;
    }

    public static void setAcumuladorDHilos(int acumuladorDHilos) {
        // VAux.tiempo = tiempo; De esta forma solo asignas el valor de tiempo a la variable VAux.tiempo 
        // que siempre será 1.
        VAux.acumuladorDHilos += acumuladorDHilos; // de esta forma el valor que tenga acumuladorDHilos se le suma el nuevo valor acumuladorDHilos 
    }

}

public class Atleta extends Thread {
    private String relevo;

    public Atleta(String relevo) {
        super(relevo);
    }

    public void run() {
        double tiempo = 0;
        synchronized (getClass()) {
            if (VAux.getTiempo() == 0) {
                System.out.println("Comienza a correr " + getName());
                tiempo = (double) (Math.random() * (11 - 9) + 9);
                VAux.setTiempo(+tiempo);
                //Enviar +1 solo quiere decir que es positivo, al igual que enviar 1.
                VAux.setAcumuladorDHilos(1);
                getClass().notifyAll();

            } else {
                System.out.println("pasa el relevo y comienza a correr " + getName());
                tiempo = (double) (Math.random() * (11 - 9) + 9);
                VAux.setTiempo(+tiempo);
                //Enviar +1 solo quiere decir que es positivo, , al igual que enviar 1.
                VAux.setAcumuladorDHilos(1);
                getClass().notifyAll();
            }

            try {
                System.out.println("el dorsal: " + getName() + " ha tardado: " + tiempo);

// Debes pasar la lógica del if a este punto para evitar que todos los hilos ejecuten esta condicion,
// al tener los procesos en wait todos se irán deteniendo en ese punto y al notificar  getClass().notifyAll();
// todos los hilos reanudarían la ejecución llegando al if y ejecutándolo, porque el valor de la variable VAux.hilosAUsar seria 4,
// esto se debe a que al ser estática comparte el valor entre todos los hilos.

                if (VAux.hilosAUsar == VAux.getAcumuladorDHilos()) {
                    System.out.println("final de la carrera, timepo total: " + VAux.getTiempo());
                }
                getClass().wait();
            } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e) {
            }
            getClass().notifyAll();


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: funciona de lujo. Me comenta un amigo que tener la clase de variables auxiliares es un poco chapuza alguna idea de como mejorarlo?

Comment: Bueno para mejorarlo podrías utilizar Future Interface que te evita mucha de la complejidad de los Thread y te permite retornar un objecto, con esto puedes retornar los datos del tiempo que ha tardado sin tener que utilizar la una clase para llevar el control, lo otro es que en tu ejemplo no se ve la utilidad de los hilos porque parece una simulación de relevo la cual es secuencial, diferente a una carrera de velocidad que cada uno seria independiente.

Comment: Además, no está especificado cual es el requerimiento de lo que se buscas con tu ejemplo, porque en tu pregunta no lo específicas, ya que no es solo mejorarlo, sino que cumpla una función y esa es la parte que no sabemos, algo importante cuando la comunidad de StackOverflow insiste en ser lo más detallado posible con las preguntas, por eso solo te di la solución a lo que pedias por falta de más datos, intenta investigar  y cuando tengas problemas pregunta  de nuevo que es parte del aprendizaje.

Answer (score 0):

Quizá el **ExecutorService** te sea de ayuda. [Tienes más info por aquí](https://crunchify.com/how-to-run-multiple-threads-concurrently-in-java-executorservice-approach/) y [por aquí](https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial)

En resumidas cuentas:

1. La clase Atleta, en vez de extender de Thread, extiendela de Runnable
2. En el void main, lanza el ExecutorService con todos los threads que quieras y haces un executor.execute

Comment: pero entonces el get name no me vale no se que hacer con el entonces